# Can I attack both the player and a planeswalker the same turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

Can I have some creatures attack the planeswalker and other creatures attack the player?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, after you choose which creatures are attacking, you may choose whether they are attacking the defending player or a planeswalker that player controls.

From the [comprehensive rules](http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20110930.txt):

> 508.1. First, the active player declares attackers. This turn-based action doesn't use the stack. To declare attackers, the active player
>   follows the steps below, in order. If at any point during the
>   declaration of attackers, the active player is unable to comply with
>   any of the steps listed below, the declaration is illegal; the game
>   returns to the moment before the declaration (see rule 717, "Handling
>   Illegal Actions").
>
> 508.1a The active player chooses which creatures that he or she controls, if any, will attack. The chosen creatures must be untapped,
>   and each one must either have haste or have been controlled by the
>   active player continuously since the turn began.
>
> 508.1b If the defending player controls any planeswalkers, or the game allows the active player to attack multiple other players, the active
>   player announces which player or planeswalker each of the chosen
>   creatures is attacking.